# Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView Intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea, admob, ads, adview

Im relatively new to programming and im having trouble with ads in my android app. My app crashes on start and I get this error:

```
02-08 20:52:47.321: E/AndroidRuntime(23492): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.Menu}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

Heres my activity:

```
public class Menu extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);

    String UrlPath="android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.menibg;

    final VideoView gif = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.banim);
    gif.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(UrlPath));
    gif.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            gif.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });

    AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ads);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(request);

    final Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
    final Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, Achievements.class);

    final ImageView bplay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.play);
    final ImageView bachieve = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.achievements);

    final View.OnClickListener buttonClickListener;
    buttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (view == bplay){
                startActivity(intent);
            }else if (view == bachieve){
                startActivity(intent1);
            }

        }
    };

    bplay.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
    bachieve.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);


}

}
```

and my xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.ads"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:gravity="bottom">

<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<VideoView
        android:id="@+id/banim"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        />
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:gravity="center">
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/play"
        android:src="@drawable/play"
        />
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/achievements"
        android:src="@drawable/achievements"
        />

</LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ads"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitID="xxxxxxxxxx"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:loadAdONCreate="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Ive found similar questions and it should have something to do with the jar file and how its added. I have it in my libs folder and added as a library. Maybe the iml should be edited? I dont see what the problem, probably because of my lack of experience. I was hoping i could get some help here.

I use Intellij 11.1.2

Comment: What jat have you copied to libs? Admob or PlayServices? And IntelliJ11 is *very* old. Consider upgrading to IntelliJ14

Comment: Ik its a very old version, and i have 14 installed but i find this version simpler. I copied the google play services jar